# parent.env( x ) confusion

Tags: r

I've read the documentation for parent.env() and it seems fairly straightforward - it returns the enclosing environment.  However, if I use parent.env() to walk the chain of enclosing environments, I see something that I cannot explain.  First, the code (taken from "R in a nutshell")

```
library( PerformanceAnalytics )
x = environment(chart.RelativePerformance)
while (environmentName(x) != environmentName(emptyenv())) 
{ 
    print(environmentName(parent.env(x)))
    x <- parent.env(x)
}
```

And the results:

```
[1] "imports:PerformanceAnalytics"
[1] "base"
[1] "R_GlobalEnv"
[1] "package:PerformanceAnalytics"
[1] "package:xts"
[1] "package:zoo"
[1] "tools:rstudio"
[1] "package:stats"
[1] "package:graphics"
[1] "package:utils"
[1] "package:datasets"
[1] "package:grDevices"
[1] "package:roxygen2"
[1] "package:digest"
[1] "package:methods"
[1] "Autoloads"
[1] "base"
[1] "R_EmptyEnv"
```

How can we explain the "base" at the top and the "base" at the bottom?  Also, how can we explain "package:PerformanceAnalytics" and "imports:PerformanceAnalytics"?  Everything would seem consistent without the first two lines.  That is, function chart.RelativePerformance is in the package:PerformanceAnalytics environment which is created by xts, which is created by zoo, ... all the way up (or down) to base and the empty environment.

Also, the documentation is not super clear on this - is the "enclosing environment" the environment in which another environment is created and thus walking parent.env() shows a "creation" chain?

**Edit**

Shameless plug: I wrote a [blog post](http://obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/) that explains environments, parent.env(), enclosures, namespace/package, etc. with intuitive diagrams.

Comment: thanks to all who contributed on this questions.  Was tough to pick an answer because all posts were great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first few items in your results give evidence of the rules R uses to search for variables used in functions in packages with namespaces.  From the [R-ext manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-namespaces):

> The namespace controls the search strategy for variables used by functions in the package.
>   If not found locally, R searches the package namespace first, then the imports, then the base
>   namespace and then the normal search path.

Elaborating just a bit, have a look at the first few lines of `chart.RelativePerformance`:

```
head(body(chart.RelativePerformance), 5)
# {
#     Ra = checkData(Ra)
#     Rb = checkData(Rb)
#     columns.a = ncol(Ra)
#     columns.b = ncol(Rb)
# }
```

When a call to `chart.RelativePerformance` is being evaluated, each of those symbols --- whether the `checkData` on line 1, or the `ncol` on line 3 --- needs to be found somewhere on the search path.  Here are the first few enclosing environments checked:

- First off is `namespace:PerformanceAnalytics`. `checkData` is found there, but `ncol` is not.
- Next stop (and the first location listed in your results) is `imports:PerformanceAnalytics`. This is the list of functions specified as imports in the package's `NAMESPACE` file. `ncol` is not found here either.
- The `base` environment namespace (where `ncol` will be found) is the last stop before proceeding to the normal search path. Almost any R function will use some `base` functions, so this stop ensures that none of that functionality can be broken by objects in the global environment or in other packages.  (R's designers could have left it to package authors to explicitly import the `base` environment in their `NAMESPACE` files, but adding this default pass through `base` does seem like the better design decision.)

Comment: Josh - but I'm calling parent.env() which is the enclosing environment.  Am I misunderstanding what parent.env() is supposed to do?  According to the chain above, the gobal environment is a "parent" or "encloses" base and down the line base encloses "Autoloads" so in effect base encloses base!  So are we saying that parent.env() is really not the enclosing environment until you get to the global environment?

Comment: @SFun28 My (imperfect) understanding is that "parent-child" can be a misleading metaphor for env's. An enclosing env is more of a pointer of where R looks next than a strict containment relationship. So you can probably construct all sorts of non-intuitive chains of env's that loop back on themselves.

Comment: Oh - I think I see your concern.  As G. Grothendieck & kohske emphasized, the first `base` searched is called `namespace:base`, to make this search mechanism possible.  Its contents are identical to `package:base`, as shown by trying `identical(ls(baseenv()), ls(.BaseNamespaceEnv))`

Comment: Also, what @joran said. Thinking about these as pointers-to-where-to-search-next is the more accurate metaphor for thinking about what `parent.env()` shows. You can't go wrong thinking about it that way (since it's super close to what R is actually doing).

Comment: @JoshO'Brien - thanks for elaborating on your answer, it helped a lot!  Also helps a lot to see that baseenv() and .BaseNamespaceEnv have the same contents although they are different environments.  It makes sense in context of your comment about the base environment being implicitly imported so that none of that functionality can be broken by global env

Answer (score 5):

1) Regarding how `base` could be there twice (given that environments form a tree), its the fault of the `environmentName` function.  Actually the first occurrence is `.BaseNamespaceEnv` and the latter occurrence is `baseenv()`.

```
> identical(baseenv(), .BaseNamespaceEnv)
[1] FALSE
```

2) Regarding the `imports:PerformanceAnalytics` that is a special environment that R sets up to hold the imports mentioned in the package's NAMESPACE or DESCRIPTION file so that objects in it are encountered before anything else.

Try running this for some clarity.  The `str(p)` and following `if` statements will give a better idea of what `p` is:

```
library( PerformanceAnalytics )
x <- environment(chart.RelativePerformance)
str(x)
while (environmentName(x) != environmentName(emptyenv())) { 
    p <- parent.env(x)
    cat("------------------------------\n")
    str(p)
    if (identical(p, .BaseNamespaceEnv)) cat("Same as .BaseNamespaceEnv\n")
    if (identical(p, baseenv())) cat("Same as baseenv()\n")
    x <- p
}
```

Comment: That's fantastic!  The parent.env relationship is a lot easier to see with this code.  I'm curious, what is the advantage of importing in a package?  I have created my own package but don't use imports.  Its it simply to find symbols more quickly or give a symbol higher precedence than the same symbol in base?

Comment: By using `import`, you can make objects in the import packages invisible to users. If your package A imports B, you can use objects of B from your package. But users cannot use the objects of B even after loading A.

Comment: by the way, this is a great utility/helper function (i.e. wrapping your code in a function called SearchPath(x) ).  It seems that R provides a search() and searchpaths() function, but doesn't let us specify a starting point other than globalenv

Comment: @kohske - but how is that different from adding Package B in the "Depends" section?  Two difference I see is the order of symbols in the search path and that symbols in Package B are visible to the user in the Depends approach?

Comment: @SFun28 *Probably* visibility is the most important thing. Here is the details: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file you can find when you should use import and when use depends.

Comment: thanks!  I'll start a new post on this.  I've read the link you posted in the past but the distinction still does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

The second `base` is `.BaseNamespaceEnv`, while the second to last `base` is `baseenv()`. These are not different (probably w.r.t. its parents). The parent of `.BaseNamespaceEnv` is `.GlobalEnv`, while that of `baseenv()` is `emptyenv()`.

In a package, as @Josh says, R searches the namespace of the package, then the imports, and then the base (i.e., `BaseNamespaceEnv`).

you can find this by, e.g.:

```
> library(zoo)

> packageDescription("zoo")
Package: zoo

# ... snip ...

Imports: stats, utils, graphics, grDevices, lattice (>= 0.18-1)

# ... snip ...

> x <- environment(zoo)

> x
<environment: namespace:zoo>

> ls(x) # objects in zoo
  [1] "-.yearmon"                "-.yearqtr"                "[.yearmon"               
  [4] "[.yearqtr"                "[.zoo"                    "[<-.zoo"                 
# ... snip ...

> y <- parent.env(x)
> y # namespace of imported packages
<environment: 0x116e37468>
attr(,"name")
[1] "imports:zoo"

> ls(y) # objects in the imported packages

   [1] "?"                                     "abline"                               
   [3] "acf"                                   "acf2AR"                               
# ... snip ...
```

Comment: kohske - ah!  I didn't realize that these are two different environments.  So truly every printed environment is a unique environment?  I'm starting to see a confusion between "namespace", "imports", and "package" environments.  Not shown is the environment of the first x which is "namespace:PerformanceAnalytics".  Could you clarify the differences between these environments, when they are loaded, and how they relate to each other?